# cannot login to sql server with new user created

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012

I created a login named  **logintest** (SQL Authentication) then i created a user named **usertest** with this login

the user creation is successful, And i changed the authentication mode to mixed mode and also restarted the services SQLSERVERAGENT and MSSQLSERVER

and still this error appear when i try to login with the new user created

Cannot connect to SARAH.

> Login failed for user 'usertest'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Comment: Is that windows Authentication or SQL Authentication

Comment: i changed the sql server instance authentication to " sql server and windows authentication" from the security tab

Comment: Do logintest has all the permissions to create user? Check in Security > logins/User tab that there is user usertest

Comment: What are the rights given to the login? What are the rights given to the user? Is the login enabled and has the right to `CONNECT` ? What is the default database for the login ?

Answer (score 0):

The login must have `CONNECT` right given.
The login must be enabled.
The default database linked to the login must be a database to which the login has rights to connect (for example by default `master` database gives rights to `guest` user to connect).

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [logintest] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [logintest]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [logintest] ENABLE
GO
```

Then make sure the password is correct and that `guest` user is enabled on `master` database.